# cluster-ssh: specify terminal font

Tags: x11, xorg, fonts, xterm, cluster-ssh

In my `cssh` config file, I have:

```
terminal_font=6x13
```

this default font is too small for me.

`man cssh` says, I can specify other font size with the `-f` argument, while using "standard X font notation". [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_(typeface)) is a wikipedia page containing some other fonts types. Unfortunately, none of these work for me:

```
$ cssh host1 host2 -f "7x14"
Fatal: Unrecognised font used (7x14).
Please amend $HOME/.clusterssh/config with a valid font (see man page).
```

Why does `"7x14"` not work? 
How can I use bigger fonts with `cssh` ?

Comment: Try running `xset q` to get the font searh path, and `find the-path` it to see if you really have the corresponding files. P.S. your wikipedia link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_(typeface) failed. P.P.S. See ArchWiki https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_Logical_Font_Description#The_Font_Search_Path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set Font Path to a directory containing "7x14" fonts.
Check out your current Font Path as:

```
xset q | grep "Font Path:" -A1
```

In the output directory list, you need to have mentioned font at least in one directory.

You can add Font Path either dynamically by `xset` or statically by modifying `xorg configuration file`.

Use command: `xset +fp desired_font_path`
Or in your xorg configuration file, add `FontPath desired_font_path` in "Files" section

Answer (score 5):

I have figured out how to use any font in `xterm`. So for the case of the mentioned `Inconsolata` font size `14`, the following works:

1) Add these 2 lines into `~/.Xresources` (create it if it does not exist)

```
XTerm*faceName: Inconsolata
XTerm*faceSize: 14
```

2) Then, tell `xterm` to use this file:

```
export XENVIRONMENT="${HOME}/.Xresources"
```

Preferably add this export into `.bashrc`, so that it is persistent.

3) comment out the font settings in `~/.clusterssh/config`, if it exists:

```
# terminal_font=6x13
```

Answer (score 3):

The largest bitmap font available via ~/.clusterssh/config is 10x20. On my 4k display I got a decent setting via:

```
terminal_args=-fa "DejaVu Sans Mono" -fs 14
terminal_size=253x100
```

ClusterSSH does not pass terminal_size as -geometry. 253x100 translated on my screen into 80 columns, ca. 30 lines.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem because I have a HiDPI display. The larger font I have in my system (Arch) is `12x24`, although I actually use `10x20` because it look better:

```
cssh -f 10x20 ...
```

Found them by looking in `/usr/share/fonts/misc/font.alias`. As per [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_Logical_Font_Description#Aliases), `font.alias` are files that map human friendly stuff like *10x20* to computer friendly stuff like *-misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--20-200-75-75-c-100-iso8859-1*.

Get the list of the font directories with the `xset q` command and the look for `font.alias` inside those dirs. Pick an alias that suits you.