# Configuring ClusterSSH to Use Freetype Fonts

Tags: fonts, cluster-ssh

I have read the question [cluster-ssh: specify terminal font](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/230106/10489) and confirmed that my configuration works fine with valid non-Freetype font names as passed to, e.g., `xfontsel`. However, I would like to use Freetype fonts instead.

With `urxvt` I specify my font as `xft:Source Code Pro:size=9` in my X resources; the same specification works fine when given directly with the `-fn` command line option.

However, if I use the same specification with the `-f` option to `cssh` or the `terminal_font` setting in `.clusterssh/config` I get an error message:

```
Fatal: Unrecognised font used (xft:Source Code Pro:size=9).
Please amend $HOME/.clusterssh/config with a valid font (see man page).
```

How can I specify this font to ClusterSSH?

(For those whom might be helped by a look at the source code, the error originates in the `get_font_size()` function of `/usr/share/perl5/App/ClusterSSH.pm` on my system; I suspect it's the `$xdisplay->QueryFont($font);` call that's failing.)

Comment: Proposed reopening as per OP's addendum: "I have read the question cluster-ssh: specify terminal font and confirmed that my configuration works fine with valid non-Freetype font names as passed to, e.g., xfontsel. However, I would like to use Freetype fonts instead."